# Utop from Ocaml brew throws error

Tags: linux, debian, ocaml, ldd, ocamlfind

I have used ocamlbrew to install ocaml and associated utilities. I had one earlier installation also. As said in the documentation, I have used /opt for installing ocamlbrew. But when I run utop as a normal user, I am getting error

```
Fatal error: cannot load shared library dllunix
Reason: /usr/local/lib/ocaml/stublibs/dllunix.so: undefined symbol: caml_stat_alloc_string
```

Also

```
ldconfig -p | grep dllunix
```

returns nothing

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I recommend you use opam to install OCaml tools and libraries.

Comment: use **opam** for everything

Comment: But the problem is I couldnt install Opam from source. Its throwing error. SO I switched to Ocamlbrew

Comment: i think you should go back to figuring out your issue with Opam. You'll be much happier with it. Start by answering the question posed to you in that thread you started.

Comment: The main intention of ocamlbrew at this point it to make it (slightly) easier to install ocaml + opam from source.  opam is definitely the way to go when setting up and using OCaml.

Answer (score 0):

This instructions are very good (and work): https://github.com/realworldocaml/book/wiki/Installation-Instructions

Install OPAM from brew, then use it for everything, including OCaml. It's best if you uninstall OCaml you've installed through brew first.